# In jmeter, how can we restrict each thread to read on csv line only?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

**Objective**:
I have csv files with unique data e.g say 200 lines. I want to run endurance test, which  executed for duration e.g 10min and avail a unique data from csv.
**Setup**:
Conisdering this, i did stepping thread setup as below with "shared mode: All threads". And i was expecting each min/60sec, 20 **new** threads will add and so on till 10min (expecting 200 threads at the end). With Stop thread EOF- True ( want to process data once no dup) and Recycle of EOF= False.
However,API executed in one min only and csv data read by few threads < 20 and done (EOF encounter), though jmeter honoring next 9min without executing my API's.

**Expectation** : 200 threads will read 200 lines i.e each thread 1 line and occurance of thread will be 20 threads in 60sec. Same like diagram, without doing Stop thread EOF=false. In nutshell, each thread execute once and then stop like kind of stuff.

Any sugeestion, how could i acheive this? Thanks!!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your setup each thread will read next line from the CSV file on each **iteration**

For example:

- Thread 1 starts
- Thread 1 reads line 1 from CSV
- Thread 1 executes 1st sampler, response time is 1 second
- Thread 1 executes 2nd sampler, response time is 2 seconds
- Thread 1 starts 2nd iteration
- Thread 1 reads line 2 from CSV
- etc.

So you either need to switch to the Thread Group implementation which has `Threads iterations limit` setting like [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) or [Arrivals Thread Group or  Free-Form Arrivals Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-arrivals-thread-group-and-the-free-form-arrivals-thread-group/)

[image]

If you want to continue with your Stepping Thread Group - you need to slow down your threads using [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers)